# Does Monogame have development support for Kindle Fire HD?

Tags: monogame, kindle-fire

I was wondering if it is possible to develop apps for Kindle Fire HD using Monogame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Kindle Fire simply runs Android with the Amazon App Store instead of the Play Store.

Everything should just work as long as you can deploy either via the store or locally.

Here's someone who confirms this -http://monogame.codeplex.com/discussions/356413